# c# winforms - Inherited items in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, data-binding, listbox-control

I want to list items in Listbox control.
The items derived from abstract base class.
Also, I need to support 2-way binding.

The base class called 'Animal'.
The inherited classes called 'Dog' and 'Cat' and have unique properties.
When selected item is changed in listbox, I want to preview the properties for the derived item.

**base class:**

```
public abstract class Animal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string _Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }


    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    { 
        get
        {
            return _Id;

        }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Dog class**

```
public class Dog  : Animal
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

}
```

**Cat Class**

```
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private string _uniqueCatProp;
    public string uniqueCatProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _uniqueCatProp;
        }
        set
        {
            _uniqueCatProp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("uniqueCatProp");
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

[image: This is my form]
Form code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingList<Animal> animals = new BindingList<Animal>();


        Dog d1 = new Dog();
        d1.Id = 1;
        d1.Name = "dog1";

        Dog d2 = new Dog();
        d2.Id = 2;
        d2.Name = "dog2";

        Cat c1 = new Cat();
        c1.Id = 3;
        c1.Name = "cat1";
        c1.uniqueCatProp = "clean";

        animals.Add(d1);
        animals.Add(d2);
        animals.Add(c1);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = typeof(Animal);

        foreach (var item in animals)
        {
            bs.Add(item);
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = bs;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Name";

        Binding ctx1 = new Binding("Text", listBox1.DataSource, "Id", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(ctx1);

        Binding ctx2 = new Binding("Text", listBox1.DataSource, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add(ctx2);
```

**The Binding is destroyed when I add the following lines:**

```
Binding ctx3 = new Binding("Text", listBox1.DataSource, "uniqueCatProp", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBox3.DataBindings.Add(ctx3);
```

I understand that the property "uniqueCatProp" is not exist in Animal base class, however I don't think that I should add another virtual property called "uniqueCatProp" to the base class.

Need your help.

Comment: if you like bindings so much, why not use wpf

Comment: The question is just an example of my app that already built and implemented in winforms.
I know that WPF is more suitable in this case, However, I would like to know how we should solve this requirement in winforms.

Comment: use events instead

Answer (score 0):

Animal Type can not see _uniqueCatProp OR uniqueCatProp

listBox1.DataSource must be Cat to work

```
Animal a = new Cat();

a.uniqueCatProp  // ERROR since Animal has no uniqueCatProp
```

The Solution is to add uniqueCatProp to Animal or make DataSource of type Cat